# How to explicitly define an associative array with key-value pairs in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value, keyvaluepair

I'm having an array called `$enquiries_labels`. It's a static array. So, I've defined it as follows:

```
$enquiries_labels = array("New Enquiry","Retail Enquiry","Feedback","Payment Query","Package Query","Test Query");
```

But instead of this I want to define an associative array explicitly with keys starting from 0 and the associated values should be in above sequence. Can anyone help me in defining such associative array with key-value pairs explicitly?

Comment: keys will be assigned automatically the way you are expecting...

Comment: Perhaps reading the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) would help

Comment: Default key start from zero in php. Read [arrays](http://in3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) for more details.

Comment: it already can be accessed by keys you want.

Comment: Is http://php.net/array_combine what you're looking for?

Comment: Try and you will see what posters above are trying to tell you.                                                                 
for($i = 0; $c < count($enquiries_labels); $c++) {
    echo $enquiries_labels[$c] . "<br />";
}

Comment: @zerkms, Why suggest that ?

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: "I want to define an associative array explicitly with keys starting from 0 and the associated values should be in above sequence." --- this sentence I treat like OP has 2 arrays: one with keys and another with values.

Comment: @zerkms, Calling a function like `array_combine()` is an overhead in this case. Why not suggest `$someassocarray = $enquiries_labels;` or tell the OP to use the very same array.

Comment: @Shankar Damodaran: I have no idea what you're talking about. The question is really fuzzy and seems like you understand it not like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the array like this.

```
$enquiries_labels = array("Key1" => "New Enquiry", "Key2" => "Retail Enquiry","Key3" =>  "Feedback", "Key4" => "Payment Query","Key5" => "Package Query", "Key6" => "Test Query");
```

Write down Key you want here.

```
$enquiries_labels = array("New Enquiry","Retail Enquiry","Feedback","Payment Query","Package Query","Test Query");
```

This array will generate key from 0 onward & you will get keys and values like this.

```
foreach ($enquiries_labels as $key => $value) {
   echo $key;
   echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($enquiries_labels as $key => $value) {
   echo $key;
   echo $value;
}
```

It already supports that.
Working [DEMO](https://eval.in/86679).

Doc says 
`Syntax "index => values", separated by commas, define index and values. index may be of type string or integer. When index is omitted, an integer index is automatically generated, starting at 0. If index is an integer, next generated index will be the biggest integer index + 1`

[Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) to php manual.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP Documentation says...

> Syntax "index => values", separated by commas, define index and
>   values. index may be of type string or integer. When index is omitted,
>   an integer index is automatically generated, **starting at 0.** If
>   index is an integer, next generated index will be the biggest integer
>   index + 1. Note that when two identical index are defined, the last
>   overwrite the first. Having a trailing comma after the last defined
>   array entry, while unusual, is a valid syntax.

So in that case... just do a `print_r($enquiries_labels);` and get yourself verified...

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => New Enquiry
    [1] => Retail Enquiry
    [2] => Feedback
    [3] => Payment Query
    [4] => Package Query
    [5] => Test Query
)
```